# Vue.js checkboxes not working with model that uses Laravel SparkForm

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-spark

I have the following checkboxes set up:

```
<label v-for="service in team.services">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.services" :id="service.name" :value="service.id"/>
</label>
```

These are displayed correctly but when checking one checkbox they all get checked as the form.services model gets set to false / true.

However, when changing the model to another data attribute e.g. 'services' everything works as expected. Any reason why this isn't working within SparkForm?

Example data:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            form: new SparkForm({
                userId: null,
                services: [] // always only gets set as true / false
            }),
            services: [], // works fine
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
      return {
        form : {
           services : []
        },
      team : {
        services : [
         {
         "name" : "Service name #1",
         "id" : 1
         },
         {
         "name" : "Service name #2",
         "id" : 2
         }
        ]
      }
     }
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <label v-for="service in team.services">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.services" :value="service.id"/>{{service.name}}
  </label>
{{form.services}}
</div>
```